# What is the "opposite" of LIKE in sql?

Tags: sql, search

I want to do a search in my Database, that gives me the id of all fields, that a given string would contain. So if I have the string "a, b, c" and the fields a and b i want them to be shown. Is there an easy way to do it with SQL? My mind seems to be stuck right now.

I could use the LIKE operator on every possible substring of my string or just compare strings without sql, but I'm hoping for an easier, better solution.

For example:
if I have my table like this:

| id | substring |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'hello' |
| 2 | 'two' |
| 3 | 'test' |

And an input-string like: "hello, this is a test"

I want to get the information, that my input sentence contains the substrings with the ids 1 and 3

Comment: Please rephrase your question by showing clear sample input table and the expected output.

Comment: hey, I geave an example, hope it helps

Comment: your title and question are two different things. The opposite of LIKE is NOT LIKE but that seems unrelated to your actual question.

Comment: Just the other way around, `where 'hello, this is a test' like '%' || substring || '%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgresql you can use the [`~` opperator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

```sql
WITH test AS (
SELECT 1 as id,
       'hello' as str
UNION
SELECT 2 as id,
       'two' as str
UNION
SELECT 3 as id,
       'test' as str
)
SELECT * FROM test WHERE 'hello, this is a test' ~ str
```

output:

```
id|str  |
--+-----+
 1|hello|
 3|test |
```

See this query in action: https://dbfiddle.uk/Tg_ao0tm

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like getting all the words and creating a IN query:

```
var sql = "select * from mytable where searchfield IN (" + string.Join(", " , inputstr.Split(intowords).Select(encodeforSQL)) + ")";
```